# Javascript won't run in Bootstrap/Wordpress Installation

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a project to use parts of Bootstrap in an already existing Wordpress installation.

Before I go further here is a Fiddle of everything: http://jsfiddle.net/xe5UX/27/

I'm trying to use the tabs element of Bootstrap to differentiate between

Now, the problem is that I've gotten this code to work while in Dreamweaver and when I preview in any browser from Dreamweaver, it works.

Here is the specific HTML for the tabs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#kitchens" data-toggle="tab">Kitchens</a></li>
            <li><a href="#bathrooms" data-toggle="tab">Bathrooms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#livingAreas" data-toggle="tab">Living Areas</a></li>
```

And here is code for the first tab of content:

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="kitchens">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="gallery-box">
            <a href="Images/residential_01.jpg" rel=""><img class="img-responsive" alt="Residential Image 1" src="Images/residential_01.jpg"></a>
            <p>Pink Glasses, Black Plates, and Alien Lobsters make an elegant statement in this kitchen.</p>
        </div>  
        <div class="gallery-box">
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="Residential Image 2" src="Images/residential_02.jpg"><p>Want some green apples?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-box">
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="Residential Image 3" src="Images/residential_03.jpg"><p>Don't let your ex-wife near the knives</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">    
        <div class="gallery-box"> 
            <img alt="Residential Image 5" src="Images/residential_05.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-box">
            <img alt="Residential Image 7" src="Images/residential_07.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-box">
            <img alt="Residentail Image 8" src="Images/residential_08.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="gallery-box">    
            <img alt="Residential Image 13" src="Images/residential_13.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-box">
            <img alt="Residential Image 14" src="Images/residential_14.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-box">
            <img alt="Residential Image 16" src="Images/residential_16.jpg">
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="gallery-box">
            <img alt="Residential Image 19" src="Images/residential_19.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-box">
            <img alt="Residential Image 20" src="Images/residential_20.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="bathrooms">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="gallery-box">
            <img alt="Residential Image 6" src="Images/residential_06.jpg">
        </div>                
        <div class="gallery-box">
            <img alt="Residential Image 9" src="Images/residential_09.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-box">
            <img alt="Residential Image 11" src="Images/residential_11.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="gallery-box">
            <img alt="Residential Image 12" src="Images/residential_12.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-box">
            <img alt="Residential Image 18" src="Images/residential_18.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any assistance on this issue. This is an issue I've worked at and worked at but can not seem to figure out.

Comment: Have you looked at your browser console? Are errors being thrown? Are you sure the correct js/css is being loaded by the browser?

Comment: get a lot more help not putting whole bootsrap plugin in code block of fiddle, just link to a cdn source

Comment: if works in local version something likely wrong with some file paths on server version...look in network tab of browser console

Comment: Thank you everyone. There aren't any errors being thrown. And I'm going to double check all of the file paths.

Comment: The update is that my javascript doesn't seem to be running on the page or it's not getting triggered. I know that the correct CSS is loading through my wp_enqueue_scripts additions to the custom functions.php and the javascript file seems to be loading... just not running.

Comment: I figured it out. jQuery wasn't loading correctly. Thanks for the help. You all certainly pointed me in the right direction.